# Java HttpsServer class - support for multiple protocols?

Tags: java, ssl, httpserver

I am creating a simple HttpsServer:

```
    public void start(String a_sAddress, int a_nPort, HashMap<String, HttpHandler> a_mapString2HttpHandler) throws IOException {

  // skipped several irrelevant lines...
    
    try {
        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance( "SSL" );
        sslContext.init( null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom() );

    //  Init a configuration with our SSL context
        HttpsConfigurator configurator = new HttpsConfigurator(sslContext);
    
       HttpsServer server = HttpsServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), a_nPort);
       
       server.setHttpsConfigurator(configurator);

       a_mapString2HttpHandler.forEach((path, handler) -> {
            
            System.out.println("Register an HttpsHandler for " + path);
            server.createContext(path, handler);
        });

       server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
       server.start();
    }
    catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        System.out.println("HttpsRequest - KeyManagementException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        System.out.println("HttpsRequest - NoSuchAlgorithmException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I use SSLContext.getInstance( "SSL" ); to support SSL.
Is there a way I can support more than one protocol? for example SSL and TLS?

Comment: SSL is outdated and insecure - you should no longer use it. Just use `TLS` instead.

Comment: @Robert Hi, it is not to be set by me... I should receive messages from other machine I do not control. And it sends SSL.